# Sudoku generator using seed Sudoku

Tags: java, sudoku, shuffle

I have created a Sudoku generator in Java. Here I am using a basic solved sudoku as seed and by transposing it and shuffling its row and columns I get a new solved sudoku.

```
 //import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.Random;

public class SudokuGenerator {
    private char[][] board = new char[9][9];
    private int[] randomizeSudoku = new int[9];
    private char[][] transposedSeed = new char[][]{{'8', '2', '7', '1', '5', '4', '3', '9', '6'},
            {'9', '6', '5', '3', '2', '7', '1', '4', '8'},
            {'3', '4', '1', '6', '8', '9', '7', '5', '2'},
            {'5', '9', '3', '4', '6', '8', '2', '7', '1'},
            {'4', '7', '2', '5', '1', '3', '6', '8', '9'},
            {'6', '1', '8', '9', '7', '2', '4', '3', '5'},
            {'7', '8', '6', '2', '3', '5', '9', '1', '4'},
            {'1', '5', '4', '7', '9', '6', '8', '2', '3'},
            {'2', '3', '9', '8', '4', '1', '5', '6', '7'},};
    private char[][] seed = new char[9][9];
    private Random random = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SudokuGenerator s = new SudokuGenerator();
        int n = 2;
        s.transpose();
        s.shuffle();
        s.seedChanger();
        while (n > 0) {
            System.out.println("\n\n------ New Board --------\n");
            s.transpose();
            s.shuffle();
            s.display();
            s.seedChanger();
            n--;
        }
    }

    private void transpose() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                seed[j][i] = transposedSeed[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    private void seedChanger() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            System.arraycopy(board[i], 0, transposedSeed[i], 0, board.length);
        }
    }

    private void randomSudokuGenerator() {
        for (int i = 0; i < randomizeSudoku.length; i++) {
            randomizeSudoku[i] = 9;
        }
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < randomizeSudoku.length; ++i) {
            int r = random.nextInt(2);
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < i; ++i1) {
                int x = randomizeSudoku[i1];
                if (x == r) {
                    if (i < 3) {
                        r = random.nextInt(3);
                    } else if (i < 6) {
                        r = random.nextInt(3) + 3;
                    } else if (i < 9) {
                        r = random.nextInt(3) + 6;
                    }
                    i1 = -1;
                }
            }
            randomizeSudoku[i] = r;
        }
    }

    private void shuffle() {
        randomSudokuGenerator();
//        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randomizeSudoku));
        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
            board[0][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[0]][x];
            board[1][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[1]][x];
            board[2][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[2]][x];
            board[3][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[3]][x];
            board[4][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[4]][x];
            board[5][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[5]][x];
            board[6][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[6]][x];
            board[7][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[7]][x];
            board[8][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[8]][x];
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {

            if (randomizeSudoku[0] == 0) swapping(board, x, 1, 0);
            if (randomizeSudoku[0] == 1) swapping(board, x, 2, 0);
            if (randomizeSudoku[0] == 0) swapping(board, x, 5, 4);
            if (randomizeSudoku[0] == 1) swapping(board, x, 5, 3);
            if (randomizeSudoku[0] == 2) swapping(board, x, 8, 6);
        }
    }

    private void swapping(char[][] a, int commonIndex, int first, int second) {
        char swap = a[commonIndex][first];
        a[commonIndex][first] = a[commonIndex][second];
        board[commonIndex][second] = swap;
    }

    private void display() {
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i <= 8; ++i) {
            if (i == 0) {
                System.out.print("\t\t\t_______________________________________\n\t row " + (i + 1) + "\t");
            } else {
                System.out.print("\t\t\t|---|---|---||---|---|---||---|---|---|\n\t row " + (i + 1) + "\t");
            }
            for (j = 0; j <= 8; ++j) {
                if (j == 3) {
                    System.out.print("|");
                }
                if (j == 6) {
                    System.out.print("|");
                }
                if (j == 8) {
                    System.out.println("| " + board[i][j] + " |");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("| " + board[i][j] + " ");
                }
            }
            if (i == 2) {
                System.out.println("\t\t\t|---|---|---||---|---|---||---|---|---|");
            }
            if (i == 5) {
                System.out.println("\t\t\t|---|---|---||---|---|---||---|---|---|");
            }
            if (i == 8) {
                System.out.println("\t\t\t---------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("\tcolumns   1   2   3    4   5   6    7   8   9  \n\n\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: Thanks for editing @200_success , I will try to do better next time.

Comment: @T145 using java 8,  why what happened?

Comment: Nothing. This would run on earlier versions, but knowing the version you're on gives knowledge of what tools can be used.

Comment: Oh OK, thanks. I glad to know it can be used on older versions, and yes maybe more tools of Java 8 can be used. But I have just started to learn Java,  when I made this I just knew this much tools. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this review, I'm operating under the assumption that this was a class assignment / programming challenge and/or has portions copy-pasted / is made by more than one person. The main reason for this is b/c of the excessive inconsistencies w/ formatting. Which is a pretty good segway into:

**Formatting**

Since you're using Java, I'll briefly touch on OOD (Object Oriented Design). Even though this is a controlled program / script, it would be a good practice to split up your `main` function into a separate class. This will let you design your Sedoku solver as a separate object. This is pretty important since you use `SudokuGenerator` in your `main` function.

On to styling, your `for` loops have awkwardly inconsistent formatting. You bounce btwn. using `++i` and `i++` (I prefer prefix b/c it used to give a performance boost, though now it probably doesn't matter), declaring variables inside and outside the loops, and using `i < 9` and `i <= 8`. The principle here is to just one form of logic. So let's start just lightly changing the program using these principles.

**`Main.java`**

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SudokuGenerator gen = new SudokuGenerator();
        // initial transpose, shuffle & seedChange happens in a constructor
        for (int i = 2; i > 0; --i) {
            System.out.println("\n\n------ New Board --------\n");
            gen.transpose();
            gen.shuffle();
            gen.display();
            gen.seedChanger();
        }
        /*
        int n = 2;
        s.transpose();
        s.shuffle();
        s.seedChanger();
        while (n > 0) {
            System.out.println("\n\n------ New Board --------\n");
            s.transpose();
            s.shuffle();
            s.display();
            s.seedChanger();
            n--;
        }
        */
    }
```

As the comment here says, the initial stuff you did to prepare the generator is now handled in its default constructor. You never edit `n` in those calls, so just declaring and modifying it in a `for` loop over a `while` is best here.

**After some modification**

**`Main.java`**

```java
package T145.sudokugen;

public class Main {

    static char[][] transposedSeed = new char[][] {
        {'8', '2', '7', '1', '5', '4', '3', '9', '6'},
        {'9', '6', '5', '3', '2', '7', '1', '4', '8'},
        {'3', '4', '1', '6', '8', '9', '7', '5', '2'},
        {'5', '9', '3', '4', '6', '8', '2', '7', '1'},
        {'4', '7', '2', '5', '1', '3', '6', '8', '9'},
        {'6', '1', '8', '9', '7', '2', '4', '3', '5'},
        {'7', '8', '6', '2', '3', '5', '9', '1', '4'},
        {'1', '5', '4', '7', '9', '6', '8', '2', '3'},
        {'2', '3', '9', '8', '4', '1', '5', '6', '7'}
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sudoku game = new Sudoku(transposedSeed);
        // initial transpose, shuffle & seedChange happens in a constructor
        for (int i = 2; i >= 0; --i) {
            System.out.println("\n\n------ New Board --------\n");
            game.transpose();
            game.shuffle();
            game.printBoard();
            game.seedChanger();
        }
    }
}
```

**`Sudoku.java`**

```java
package T145.sudokugen;

import java.util.Random;

public class Sudoku {

    private final char[][] transposedSeed;

    private char[][] board = new char[9][9];
    private int[] randomizeSudoku = new int[9];
    private char[][] seed = new char[9][9];
    private Random random = new Random();

    public Sudoku(char[][] transposedSeed) {
        this.transposedSeed = transposedSeed;

        transpose();
        shuffle();
        seedChanger();
    }

    public void transpose() {
        for (short i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
            for (short j = 0; j < 9; ++j) {
                seed[j][i] = transposedSeed[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    public void seedChanger() {
        for (short i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
            System.arraycopy(board[i], 0, transposedSeed[i], 0, board.length);
        }
    }

    public void randomSudokuGenerator() {
        short i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < randomizeSudoku.length; ++i) {
            randomizeSudoku[i] = 9;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < randomizeSudoku.length; ++i) {
            int r = random.nextInt(2);

            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < i; ++i1) {
                int x = randomizeSudoku[i1];

                if (x == r) {
                    if (i < 3) {
                        r = random.nextInt(3);
                    } else if (i < 6) {
                        r = random.nextInt(3) + 3;
                    } else if (i < 9) {
                        r = random.nextInt(3) + 6;
                    }

                    i1 = -1;
                }
            }

            randomizeSudoku[i] = r;
        }
    }

    private void swap(char[][] a, int commonIndex, int first, int second) {
        char swap = a[commonIndex][first];
        a[commonIndex][first] = a[commonIndex][second];
        board[commonIndex][second] = swap;
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        randomSudokuGenerator();

        for (short x = 0; x < 9; ++x) {
            board[0][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[0]][x];
            board[1][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[1]][x];
            board[2][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[2]][x];
            board[3][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[3]][x];
            board[4][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[4]][x];
            board[5][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[5]][x];
            board[6][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[6]][x];
            board[7][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[7]][x];
            board[8][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[8]][x];
        }

        for (short x = 0; x < 9; ++x) {
            if (randomizeSudoku[0] == 0) {
                swap(board, x, 1, 0);
            }

            if (randomizeSudoku[0] == 1) {
                swap(board, x, 2, 0);
            }

            if (randomizeSudoku[0] == 0) {
                swap(board, x, 5, 4);
            }

            if (randomizeSudoku[0] == 1) {
                swap(board, x, 5, 3);
            }

            if (randomizeSudoku[0] == 2) {
                swap(board, x, 8, 6);
            }
        }
    }

    public void printBoard() {
        for (short i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {

            if (i == 0) {
                System.out.print("\t\t\t_______________________________________\n\t row " + (i + 1) + "\t");
            } else {
                System.out.print("\t\t\t|---|---|---||---|---|---||---|---|---|\n\t row " + (i + 1) + "\t");
            }

            for (short j = 0; j < 9; ++j) {
                if (j == 3) {
                    System.out.print("|");
                }

                if (j == 6) {
                    System.out.print("|");
                }

                if (j == 8) {
                    System.out.println("| " + board[i][j] + " |");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("| " + board[i][j] + " ");
                }
            }

            if (i == 2) {
                System.out.println("\t\t\t|---|---|---||---|---|---||---|---|---|");
            }

            if (i == 5) {
                System.out.println("\t\t\t|---|---|---||---|---|---||---|---|---|");
            }

            if (i == 8) {
                System.out.println("\t\t\t---------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("\tcolumns   1   2   3    4   5   6    7   8   9  \n\n\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A majority of this is just simple re-formatting. You'll notice I use `short` over `int` in some cases, and this is just simply b/c `short`s have less of a memory imprint. It doesn't really matter b/c of just how much memory modern computers have, but I like to produce code that pays attention to the details.

I haven't modified *any* of your core logic b/c of my initial reasoning. But to point you in the right direction, think about:

1) Where the modulo operator (`%`) can be used to clean up some operations.

2) Where you can use other [data structures to help optimize performance](https://simplenotions.wordpress.com/2009/05/13/java-standard-data-structures-big-o-notation/).

3) Where you can use Java 8+ abilities to optimize performance or at least slim down your code w/ equivalent performance.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing my code sir @T145 I have created this code on my own alone so I take full responsibility that I haven't given a structure to it and didn't use OOPS, I will try to make one code using all this concept because when I made this I didn't knew much about OOPS

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time and support @T145

Comment: sir @T145 i further optimized my code a bit and did some of the changes you recommended .

Comment: s/segway/segue  :D

Answer (score 0):

As recommended in answers , i updated my code a bit and further optimized it and tried to manage the tasks of methods.
Below are some changes i made ;

Here , i put the initial transposing and shuffling into the constructor ,

```
private SudokuGenerator() {
    this.transpose();
    this.shuffle();
    this.seedChanger();
}
```

Next i created a method generate() that generates the new sudoku ,

```
private void generate() {
        System.out.println("\n\n------ New Board --------\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < random.nextInt(5); i++) {
            this.transpose();
            this.shuffle();
            this.seedChanger();
        }
        this.display();
    }
```

I optimized one of my method where i changed similar task for all index of array by using for loop ,

old code :

```
 for (short x = 0; x < 9; ++x) {
            board[0][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[0]][x];
            board[1][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[1]][x];
            board[2][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[2]][x];
            board[3][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[3]][x];
            board[4][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[4]][x];
            board[5][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[5]][x];
            board[6][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[6]][x];
            board[7][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[7]][x];
            board[8][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[8]][x];
        }
```

optimized code :

```
for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                board[i][x] = seed[randomizeSudoku[i]][x];
            }
        }
```

And converted all `<=8` into `< 9`.

void main now :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        SudokuGenerator s = new SudokuGenerator();
        s.generate();
    }
```

Is this better now ? @T145

Comment: Try and execute the code as you have it in this post.

Comment: you mean my updated code right....? I tried this it works fine. It gives me one new random Sudoku everytime  , but I am still creating the object in the psvm of class SudokuGenerator . I know if I make my constructor public I can make an anonymous object in any class and call the method generate() and I can get a random solved Sudoku. @T145

Comment: If you were to divide your code into separate classes as I have then this code wouldn't execute. You have your `SudokuGenerator`'s constructor as private, and therefore be inaccessible. Also, your `transposedSeed` shouldn't always be constant in theory, which is another reason to go for an OOD approach. Don't forget to select an answer.

Comment: as I said earlier I know I should make my constructor public, and yes making transposed seed not constant is what I am going to think about, thanks.